# WCF Service Initialization Method with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I recently started using Castle Windsor as my main DI manager. I have several WCF service classes that needs to be instantiated with castle's WcfFacility. The only problem I am facing is that i need the ability to call an initialization method in each of the services classes and apperently castle's OnCreate method does not get called when using the AsWcfService method.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register(
                 // Filter Assemblies
                 Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(_managersDirectoryName).FilterByName(filterAssemblyByName))
                        .BasedOn<AManagerBase>() //Filter types in assembly
                        .If(t => _usedManagersTypes.ContainsKey(t.AssemblyQualifiedName)) //filter only the used managers
                        .Configure(comp =>
                        {
                            log.DebugFormat("Technology Installed: {0}", comp.Implementation.AssemblyQualifiedName);
                            comp.Named(comp.Implementation.FullName)
                            .AsWcfService()
                            .OnCreate(manager => initializeManager(manager as AManagerBase));
                        })
            );
}

private void initializeManager(AManagerBase manager)
{
   // This method never gets called
   manager.InitiateManagerResources(_dataManager, _wrapperProvider);
}
```

The WCF Services gets created and opened correctly but the initialization method never gets called.
Am I doing something wrong here or Is there any other way to accomplish that?